# AWS SNS failed for USA

Tags: amazon-web-services

I faced the problem: SMS messages are not received on phone numbers in the USA. I tested several other European phone numbers and the sending was successful.

Region us-east-1 has limit $100. In region us-east-2, only the sandbox. So when I wrote to support they said they used region us-east-2 for the US. Could that be the problem? Is it possible to redirect USA numbers to Region us-east-1?

I'm desperate with this problem. Maybe we need to confirm some corporate phone number? But SMS is sent to Italy without this option. I'm really confused Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Might help identify the problem: [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html)